Loading icon remains in release mode but disappears in debug mode
I have a signInWithEmailAndPassword function that logs in the user:
Future<void> signInWithEmailAndPassword() async {
  showDialog(
    context: context,
    builder: (context) {
      return const Center(
        child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
      );
    },
  );

  try {
    // Await the sign-in operation before popping the dialog
    await FirebaseAuth.instance.signInWithEmailAndPassword(
      email: _controllerEmail.text,
      password: _controllerPassword.text,
    );

    if (FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.emailVerified) {
      if (mounted) {
        Navigator.of(context).pop(); // Pop the dialog after sign-in

        Navigator.pushReplacement(
          context,
          MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => const MyHomePage()),
        );
      }
    } else {
      FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser?.sendEmailVerification();
      if(mounted) {
Navigator.pop(context);
      }
    }
  } on FirebaseAuthException catch (e) {
    if (mounted) {
          showToast(getLocalizedErrorMessage(e), context);
    Navigator.pop(context);
    }
  }
}

The problem is in
if (FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.emailVerified) {
  if (mounted) {
    Navigator.of(context).pop(); // Pop the dialog after sign-in

    Navigator.pushReplacement(
      context,
      MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => const MyHomePage()),
    );
      }
    }

In debug mode the CircularProgressIndicator disappears as expected but in release mode it keeps showing until the user gets rid of it.
Why is it happening?

try flutter clean
